# Does "since High school" include High school?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was applying for a Chinese visa and it was indicated that I should  list my education history since High school. Does that also include High School or is it only referring to the period after high school until now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Since' can have either inclusive or exclusive meaning depending on the context. For example "He has been staying in the hotel since Friday" is inclusive: he arrived on Friday and has been a guest continuously during the intervening period. However "He hasn't been into work since Friday" is exclusive: he was at work on Friday but has not been in on any of the subsequent days.

Similarly "I've lived in the UK since I moved here from France in August 2002" implies that the speaker took up residence during August 2002 and has lived in the UK from 2002 to the time of speaking. However the same person could say "I haven't lived in France since August 2002" because that's when they moved to the UK.

In the case of the Chinese visa application the use of "since" seems to relate to the ending of your High School education (a bit like the ending of the person's period of residence in France) so they are looking for education after that point in time.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the reference period is included depends on the context. In this case "high school" is included.

- I haven't been eating since breakfast. (*Here it is clearly "since after breakfast was finished"*)
- He is been working in a bank since leaving school. (*The time of leaving school is roughly the time when work in a bank began.*)
- We've been living here since 1994. (*The full year is unlikely to be the period; what is probably meant is that they started living there at some time in 1994, which could even be in December 1994.*)

Comment: “I haven’t eaten since breakfast” is idiomatic.

Comment: @Xanne There is no doubt it is in current use; yet it has to be analysed semantically; you assume then that the period is included, and that in this case, the illogicality forces the conclusion that we are in presence of an idiom? It should be in the idiom section in the OALD, but it is not found there.

Comment: *Idiom* and *idiomatic* are two different things.

Comment: @Xanne Then, instead of going by the definition "(of a group of words) having a particular meaning that is different from the meanings of each word considered separately" you go by the definition "natural in expression," ([Cambridge Dic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idiomatic)); that is not the point discussed,  nor does the naturalness of the usage have anything  to do with the semantic analysis of the relations brought into play. I don't understand your point, or, rather I tend to think that you have no point.  (1/2)

Comment: @Xanne "Give up the ghost" is natural, but an idiom, undecipherable from the mere words. Nevertheless, have a look at this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/261767/349876) and its answer, and see what part naturalness plays in it. It is the question that gives rise to the decision of calling the present one a duplicate. (2/2)

Comment: As you can see from my answer I disagree that High School is included in the request for information. I see the request as being similar to your "worked in a bank" example and relates to the _end_ of the applicant's High School career not the start of it.

Comment: @BoldBen I had read your conclusion but still thought the inclusion possible.  I saw nothing contradicting this possibility, and in a majority of cases inclusion is the rule. What would be the criterion here, some sort of widespread administrative practice?

Comment: That's really the problem with the application form, it's ambiguous in English. I suspect that there might be a Chinese word which is translated as 'since' but is actually unambiguous. I went with the exclusive interpretation because qualifications at High School (middle school in China) level are usually gained at the _end_ of one's time there.